# 'Where like' clause using the concatenated value of 2 columns with eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a query that searches for a term in several columns and one of them has to be a full name.

I have separated the full name in name and lastname, so I have to concat these 2 values when searching.

I have this right now only searching for name. How I would add the concat to lastname? I was investigating over mutators but I don't know if it is the way to way.

```
public function search($searchQuery)
{
    $search = "%{$searchQuery}%";

    return Order::with('customer')
                    ->orWhereHas('customer', function($query) use ($search){
                        $query->where('dni', 'like', $search);
                    })
                    ->orWhereHas('customer', function($query) use ($search){
                        $query->where('name', 'like', $search);
                    })
                    ->orWhere('code', 'like', $search)
                    ->paginate(15);
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mutators are not the way to go here, because they do not affect the query you're building, they are only used on the values stored in the model. However you can use the following condition:

```php
$query->where(DB::raw('CONCAT_WS(" ", name, lastname)'), 'like', $search);
```

The MySQL function [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) will concatenate two strings, gluing them with the string passed as the first parameter. So in this case if the first name is `John` and the last name is `Smith`, the condition will be evaluated to this `"John Smith" like "%query%"`. The `DB:raw` is used to avoid the first part of the condition to be escaped which would put backticks around the concatenation statement.

Comment: How about this.....but where the two columns you need are on a relationship you brought in using "with" :).

Answer (score 1):

I tried @bogdan's solution but had to specify the `%` in front of `$search`

```
$query->where(DB::raw('CONCAT_WS(" ", name, lastname)'), 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
```