# Sorting the list of users in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am beginner in Laravel. I use Laravel 5.8 in my project.

I have this code:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->boolean('enable')->default(0);
            $table->string('name', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('surname', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('email', 120)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->bigInteger('counter')->default(0);
            $table->string('url_address', 160);
            $table->string('account_paid_for', 12)->nullable();
            $table->string('premium_for', 12)->nullable();
            $table->string('hits', 12)->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        });


public function getUserList(string $query, string $sortColumn, string $sortMethod)
    {
        if ($query != "") {
            return User::ofRoleType(['user', 'userPremium', 'userCompany', 'userSponsor', 'userGuest'])
                ->where(function ($q) use ($query, $sortColumn, $sortMethod) {
                    $q->where('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orWhere('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orWhere('surname', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orderBy($sortColumn, $sortMethod);
                })->paginate(2);
        } else {
            return User::ofRoleType(['user', 'userPremium', 'userCompany', 'userSponsor', 'userGuest'])->paginate(2);

        }
    }
```

and User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;
    use cms\Presenters\UserPresenter;

    public static $roles = [];


    protected $fillable = ['name', 'surname', 'email', 'email_verified_at', 'password', ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }

    public function mainRole()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role');
    }


    public function hasRole(array $roles)
    {

        foreach ($roles as $role) {

            if (isset(self::$roles[$role])) {
                if (self::$roles[$role]) return true;

            } else {
                self::$roles[$role] = $this->roles()->where('name', $role)->exists();
                if (self::$roles[$role]) return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I need to display a list of users in the following order:

1. First, users who have a premium account (ie a premium_for field with a larger date than today),
2. Then users with the largest number in the field "hits"
3. Other users

How can you do this? Does anyone know how to customize my getUserList function for this sort?

Comment: What are possible values for `premium_for`?

Comment: date in this format (yyyy-mm-dd): ex 2019-12-18

Comment: I think `->orderBy("premium_for","desc")
->orderBy('hits', 'DESC')
` appending should work for your case.

Comment: That's not quite the correct logic.  That will put someone with premium_for 2022 and 3 hits before someone with premium_for 2020 and 9999 hits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am light on Laravel experience, but I think you are asking for:

```
->orderBy(DB::raw('IF(premium_for > CURDATE(), 0, 1)'))
->orderBy('hits', 'DESC');
```

(Untested) This means to state:

1. Priority to anyone with premium expiry in the future.  (Doesn't matter how much in the future.)
2. Then sort by hits - biggest to smallest.

A resource explaining `DB::raw()`: https://laraveldaily.com/select-with-dbraw-make-your-database-work/

I'll also recommend that you `WS_CONCAT()` your WHERE columns and only make one LIKE comparison. Like this: ['Where like' clause using the concatenated value of 2 columns with eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33898494/2943403)

Comment: this code return: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'IF(premium_for > CURDATE(), 0, 1)

Comment: Do you need to escape it (turn off quoting)?

Comment: turn off quoting?

Comment: ok, i test it now. In account_paid_for (yyyy-mm-dd) - I have date payment. How can I view records that are still valid?

Comment: ...by adding another WHERE condition, I reckon.